# Clarification for Pathlogic settings needed

Tags: path-aliases

I have installed [Pathlogic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic) but can't get it working.

I want to have the LIVE url appended to localhost for images in basic page content items. Format is Full HTML, using [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce)

Configuration is as follows on:

admin/config/content/pathologic

Path relative to server root (/foo/bar) ***is selected***

In the box that says:

All base paths for this site, I added:

```
/sites/xuzo.dd/files/
```

When adding content images on the live site the path looks like this:

```
/testing/sites/default/files/content_images/left.png
```

When adding content images on the localhost site the path looks like this

```
/sites/xuzo.dd/files/content_images/left.png
```

I exported the database from live site to local host, still images not showing and wrong image URL...[image]

Comment: are you sure the base path is "/sites/xuzo.dd/files/" and not something like "/sites/xuzo.dd/"?

Comment: /sites/xuzo.dd/files/content_images/left.png this is the complete path when uploading images from Localhost with IMCE

Comment: /sites/xuzo.dd/files/content_images/left.png this is the complete path when uploading images from Localhost with IMCE. I have corrected the path to /sites/xuzo.dd/files/content_images/ in the backend of the live site "All Base Path for this site"

Comment: Changed settings to this    /files/content_images/  - not working